# How can i disable selected border effect of a QListsWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qlistwidget

I want to disable this border effect from a item in a QListWidget

[image]

As you can see, that QListWidget has some style sheet:

```
#language_list{
background-color: white;
selection-background-color: rgb(85, 255, 255);
margin-top: 3px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
padding: 1em;
font: 14px "Roboto";
color: #393939;
}
#language_list::item{
margin-bottom: 1em;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
}
#language_list::item:hover{
background-color: #E0E0E0;
padding-top:2px;
padding-left:2px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #AFAFAF;
}
#language_list::item:selected{
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #C3C2C2;
color: white;
padding-top:7px;
padding-left:7px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
border: transparent;
border-radius: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

`#language_list` is its object name

Only what you need is open QtDesigner and create a QListWidget and setting style sheet with this. Don't forget name it with `#language_list` and add some elements.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "border effect"? The gray area around the item or the *focus* border (which is dotted in your image)? Consider that what you're showing doesn't seem the standard Qt behavior, so you're probably using some style sheet. If that's the case, please provide a [mre].

Comment: i'm talking about the focus border bro, and yeah, i'm using some styles sheet

Comment: I edited my question, please help me :C